# I want to know which speed() method will be implemented among the code

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java,so it's a bit difficult for me to understand some examples at times.I want to know which speed method will be implemented among the code and the print statement of which speed() method from which class will be printed in the output?

```
   class Car{
   public Car()
   {
    System.out.println("Class Car");
   }
   public void vehicleType()
   {
    System.out.println("Vehicle Type: Car");
   }
}
class Maruti extends Car{
   public Maruti()
   {
        System.out.println("Class Maruti");
   }
  public void brand()
   {
    System.out.println("Brand: Maruti");
   }
   public void speed()
   {
    System.out.println("Max: 90Kmph");
   }
}
public class Maruti800 extends Maruti{

   public Maruti800()
   {
    System.out.println("Maruti Model: 800");
   }
   public void speed()
   {
    System.out.println("Max: 80Kmph");
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     Maruti800 obj=new Maruti800();
     obj.vehicleType();
     obj.brand();
     obj.speed();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you wanted to ask which `speed()` method will be **called** (not implemented) when you execute the code in your `main` method. Since the type of `obj` is `Maruti800` (because of `new Maruti800()`), then the `speed` method from the `Maruti800` class will be called and it will print `Max: 80Kmph`. To compare, if you declared your object like `Maruti obj = new Maruti();` then `obj.speed()` would call method `speed` from the `Maruti` class.

Comment: Thanks brother. I got it